# In Numpy, find Euclidean distance between each pair from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have two arrays of 2D coordinate points (x,y)

```
a = [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2), ... (xN,yN) ]
b = [ (X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), ... (XN,YN) ]
```

How can I find the Euclidean distances between each aligned pairs `(xi,yi) to (Xi,Yi)` in an `1xN` array?

The `scipy.spatial.cdist` function gives me distances between all pairs in an `NxN` array.

If I just use `norm` function to calculate the distance one by one it seems to be slow.

Is there a built in function to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not seeing a built-in, but you could do it yourself pretty easily.

```
distances = (a-b)**2
distances = distances.sum(axis=-1)
distances = np.sqrt(distances)
```

Comment: It amounts to the same, but it is faster to do the squaring and adding with `np.dot`: `delta = a-b; dist = np.dot(delta, delta); dist = np.sqrt(dist)`

Comment: I don't think `dot` vectorizes like that; it computes matrix products for 2-d inputs. You could probably do something with `einsum`, but I don't know the Einstein summation convention, so it's hard for me to give answers using it.

Comment: Oops! You are absolutely right, it's `inner1d` that does it: `import numpy.core.umath_tests as ut; delta = a-b; dist = np.sqrt(dnp.inner1d(delta, delta))`. Alternatively `dist = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij, ij->i', delta, delta))`.

Answer (score 2):

`hypot` is another valid alternative

```
a, b = randn(10, 2), randn(10, 2)
ahat, bhat = (a - b).T
r = hypot(ahat, bhat)
```

Result of `timeit`s between manual calculation and `hypot`:

Manual:

```
timeit sqrt(((a - b) ** 2).sum(-1))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop
```

Using `hypot`:

```
timeit hypot(ahat, bhat)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 µs per loop
```

Now how about some adult-sized arrays:

```
a, b = randn(1e7, 2), randn(1e7, 2)
ahat, bhat = (a - b).T

timeit -r10 -n3 hypot(ahat, bhat)
3 loops, best of 10: 208 ms per loop

timeit -r10 -n3 sqrt(((a - b) ** 2).sum(-1))
3 loops, best of 10: 224 ms per loop
```

Not much of a performance difference between the two methods. You can squeeze out a tiny bit more from the latter by avoiding `pow`:

```
d = a - b

timeit -r10 -n3 sqrt((d * d).sum(-1))
3 loops, best of 10: 184 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `[:, np.newaxis, :]` to the first parameter

```
np.linalg.norm(grid[:, np.newaxis, :] - scenario.target, axis=-1)
```

ref [Numpy Broadcast to perform euclidean distance vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948363/numpy-broadcast-to-perform-euclidean-distance-vectorized)