# Numpy Broadcast to perform euclidean distance vectorized

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, vectorization

I have matrices that are 2 x 4 and 3 x 4. I want to find the euclidean distance across rows, and get a 2 x 3 matrix at the end. Here is the code with one for loop that computes the euclidean distance for every row vector in a against all b row vectors. How do I do the same without using for loops?

```
 import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,9]])
dists = np.zeros((2, 3))
for i in range(2):
      dists[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a[i] - b), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply use `np.newaxis` at the right place:

```
 np.sqrt((np.square(a[:,np.newaxis]-b).sum(axis=2)))
```

Comment: Could you please explain how `Simply using np.newaxis at the right place` works? If you could start with the fact that `a` is 2x4 and `b` is 3x4, that would be great.

Answer (score 43):

Here are the original input variables:

```
A = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
B = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,9]])
A
# array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2]])
B
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 2, 1, 9]])
```

A is a 2x4 array.
B is a 3x4 array.

We want to compute the Euclidean distance matrix operation in one entirely vectorized operation, where `dist[i,j]` contains the distance between the ith instance in A and jth instance in B. So `dist` is 2x3 in this example.

The distance

[image]

could ostensibly be written with numpy as

```
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(A-B))) # DOES NOT WORK
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4) (3,4)
```

However, as shown above, the problem is that the element-wise subtraction operation `A-B` involves incompatible array sizes, specifically the 2 and 3 in the first dimension.

```
A has dimensions 2 x 4
B has dimensions 3 x 4
```

In order to do element-wise subtraction, we have to pad either A or B to satisfy numpy's broadcast rules. I'll choose to pad A with an extra dimension so that it becomes 2 x 1 x 4, which allows the arrays' dimensions to line up for broadcasting. For more on numpy broadcasting, see the [tutorial in the scipy manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and the final example in [this tutorial](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc).

You can perform the padding with either `np.newaxis` value or with the `np.reshape` command. I show both below:

```
# First approach is to add the extra dimension to A with np.newaxis
A[:,np.newaxis,:] has dimensions 2 x 1 x 4
B has dimensions                     3 x 4

# Second approach is to reshape A with np.reshape
np.reshape(A, (2,1,4)) has dimensions 2 x 1 x 4
B has dimensions                          3 x 4
```

As you can see, using either approach will allow the dimensions to line up. I'll use the first approach with `np.newaxis`. So now, this will work to create A-B, which is a 2x3x4 array:

```
diff = A[:,np.newaxis,:] - B
# Alternative approach:
# diff = np.reshape(A, (2,1,4)) - B
diff.shape
# (2, 3, 4)
```

Now we can put that difference expression into the `dist` equation statement to get the final result:

```
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(A[:,np.newaxis,:] - B), axis=2))
dist
# array([[ 3.74165739,  0.        ,  8.06225775],
#        [ 2.44948974,  2.        ,  7.14142843]])
```

Note that the `sum` is over `axis=2`, which means take the sum over the 2x3x4 array's third axis (where the axis id starts with 0).

If your arrays are small, then the above command will work just fine. However, if you have large arrays, then you may run into memory issues. Note that in the above example, numpy internally created a 2x3x4 array to perform the broadcasting. If we generalize A to have dimensions `a x z` and B to have dimensions `b x z`, then numpy will internally create an `a x b x z` array for broadcasting.

We can avoid creating this intermediate array by doing some mathematical manipulation. Because you are computing the Euclidean distance as a sum-of-squared-differences, we can take advantage of the mathematical fact that sum-of-squared-differences can be rewritten.

[image]

Note that the middle term involves the sum over **element-wise** multiplication. This sum over multiplcations is better known as a dot product. Because A and B are each a matrix, then this operation is actually a matrix multiplication. We can thus rewrite the above as:

[image]

We can then write the following numpy code:

```
threeSums = np.sum(np.square(A)[:,np.newaxis,:], axis=2) - 2 * A.dot(B.T) + np.sum(np.square(B), axis=1)
dist = np.sqrt(threeSums)
dist
# array([[ 3.74165739,  0.        ,  8.06225775],
#        [ 2.44948974,  2.        ,  7.14142843]])
```

Note that the answer above is exactly the same as the previous implementation. Again, the advantage here is the we do not need to create the intermediate 2x3x4 array for broadcasting.

For completeness, let's double-check that the dimensions of each summand in `threeSums` allowed broadcasting.

```
np.sum(np.square(A)[:,np.newaxis,:], axis=2) has dimensions 2 x 1
2 * A.dot(B.T) has dimensions                               2 x 3
np.sum(np.square(B), axis=1) has dimensions                 1 x 3
```

So, as expected, the final `dist` array has dimensions 2x3.

This use of the dot product in lieu of sum of element-wise multiplication is also discussed in [this tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/).

Comment: This answer is so useful, especially the part to overcome broadcasting issues. Thank you @stackoverflowuser2010

Comment: Wonderful answer!  But I have a question since it seems you still need to broadcast the first and the last array in the sum. Is  this still desirable?

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem recently working with deep learning(stanford cs231n,Assignment1),but when I used

```
 np.sqrt((np.square(a[:,np.newaxis]-b).sum(axis=2)))
```

There was a error

```
MemoryError
```

That means I ran out of memory(In fact,that produced a array of 500*5000*1024 in the middle.It's so huge!)

To prevent that error,we can use a formula to simplify:

[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np
aSumSquare = np.sum(np.square(a),axis=1);
bSumSquare = np.sum(np.square(b),axis=1);
mul = np.dot(a,b.T);
dists = np.sqrt(aSumSquare[:,np.newaxis]+bSumSquare-2*mul)
```

Comment: to add something;quoted from the [official document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)
`There are, however, cases where broadcasting is a bad idea because it leads to inefficient use of memory that slows computation.There are, however, cases where broadcasting is a bad idea because it leads to inefficient use of memory that slows computation.`

Comment: I am working on the same problem but the results I get using this no loop implementation don't match the ones I got using the one and two loops solutions

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is already included in [scipy's spatial module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) and I recommend using it as it will be vectorized and highly optimized under the hood. But, as evident by the other answer, there are ways you can do this yourself.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,9]])
np.sqrt((np.square(a[:,np.newaxis]-b).sum(axis=2)))
# array([[ 3.74165739,  0.        ,  8.06225775],
#       [ 2.44948974,  2.        ,  7.14142843]])
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
cdist(a,b)
# array([[ 3.74165739,  0.        ,  8.06225775],
#       [ 2.44948974,  2.        ,  7.14142843]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) also works well with broadcasting. Specifying an integer value for `axis` will use a vector norm, which defaults to Euclidean norm.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,9]])
np.linalg.norm(a[:, np.newaxis] - b, axis = 2)

# array([[ 3.74165739,  0.        ,  8.06225775],
#       [ 2.44948974,  2.        ,  7.14142843]])
```