# how to calculate euclidian distance of two numpy arrays by broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I would like to calculate the euclidian distance of two numpy arrays.

Each row in the array is a vector.

e.g.

```
a = np.array([125, 20, 210, 55], [11, 97, 111, 71])
b = np.array([51, 19, 35, 65], [59, 80, 37, 60])
```

I need to calculate the euclidian distance of each row in a with each row in b.

The actual size of the array can be large as 5000 rows and 4000 columns.

I know how to do it by two for-loops and one for-loop.
I need to solve it by vectorized numpy array.
e.g.   broadcast an array to another one like https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html

without using

```
 spatial.distance.cdist
```

but, I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948363/numpy-broadcast-to-perform-euclidean-distance-vectorized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Broadcast to perform euclidean distance vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948363/numpy-broadcast-to-perform-euclidean-distance-vectorized)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

np.sqrt((np.square(a[:,np.newaxis] - b).sum(axis=2)))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.